# Windows 10 as NTP Server not sending responses

Tags: windows-10, ntp

I'm trying to configure my Windows 10 PC to act as an NTP server. I followed the steps [here](https://www.hellpc.net/how-to-make-your-computer-a-time-server-ntp-server-without-any-software/). However, when I look in wireshark, I can clearly see the NTP poll commands coming from the client, but I see no response generated (I should, shouldn't I?). Similarly, on the NTP client interface, it also shows the error code of "No Response."

As a debug step, I performed `w32tm /query /configuration` and under NtpServer, It shows "Enabled: 1 (Local)".

I tried including a firewall exception for w32tm.exe, but that didn't seem to help either.

How should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Open up a administrative command window and type `w32tm /config /reliable:yes` then hit enter, then check to see if it works. That page you link to seems a little fishy, although people in the comments say it works, I'm not so sure.

Comment: If that doesn't work, temporarily drop the firewall and see if that does it. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like a total firewall shutdown did the trick. Do you have a clue how to specifically let this through without a total firewall shutdown?

Comment: Sure, port 123 UDP.  Your machine should be listening on that port.

Comment: I'll be more specific, setup an inbound rule, to allow a port, using the UDP protocol,the port number is 123, allow the connection, public and private, name it NTP, and hit finish.